# what is the best practice to request to Firebase Firestore in every tabBarView ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, tabbar

I am trying to request in every tab to Firebase Firestore. Still, if I do not add a `listener` to the `tabController` with `setState((){})` it does not refresh the view and the setting state adds to the screen's momentary rerendering effect. I want to avoid this effect. Thanks for all answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firestore have an awesome snapshot build right into it. you can combine that with StreamBuilder from Flutter.Streambuilder will listen to the changes from Firestore using snapshot. you don't need to worry about the state (you can use stateless) as Streambuilder with auto rebuild every time the data on your Firestore update.

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: db.collection('drugs').snapshots(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text('No Drug'),
          );
        } else {
          final list = snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((e) => Drug.fromMap(e.data()))
              .toList();
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ProductTile(list[index]);
            },
          );
        }
      })),
```

Comment: Yes I am using streamBuilder too but My tabBar has 28 tabs which shows category names when the tabController index changes I need to change the category name which I query for Firestore with. I can retrieve data from Firestore and show them in the view ,main problem for me is setting State anytime tabs are changed.

Comment: you can create a stream outside of rebuild and init it with value of the category you want to stream